# JaCoCo JUnit Ant Error : Process Fork Failed

Tags: java, ant, junit, jacoco

I have an Ant Build file. I added jacoco coverage task to get the coverage of my junit testcases. It says process fork failed.

```
<jacoco:coverage output="file" destfile="${result.exec.file}">

    <!-- forkmode="perTest" printsummary="on"  maxmemory="3072m" failureProperty="test.failure" haltonerror="false" includeAntRuntime="true"-->
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="test.run.path" />
        <syspropertyset>
            <propertyref builtin="commandline" />
        </syspropertyset>
        <!-- usefile="true"  -->
        <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
        <!-- failureproperty="test.failure" haltonerror="false" -->
        <batchtest todir="reports/junit-xml" fork="yes">
            <fileset dir="src/test/java">
                <include name="**/AllTest.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</jacoco:coverage>

<junitreport todir="${reports.dir}/junit-xml">
    <fileset dir="${reports.dir}/junit-xml">
        <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <report format="frames" todir="${reports.dir}/junit-html" />
</junitreport>
```

Comment: Does it give any more information? What are the commented out elements in your XML for?

Comment: commented out elements are attributes for the tags just below it. These elements are optional or have the default value, which being used gives the same result. 
I tried to run the build file with "-verbose" and it shows some error, which on searching says classpath is too large and windows restricts upto a certain length classpath. But that is not the issue , because on changing "fork=yes" to "fork=no" the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this without jacoco? I ask because I'm having the same problem with fork failure and I'm not using jacoco. I also have another project's ant script doing the same thing and it works fine. Yet somehow the project and ant script I'm currently working on fails the fork. In both cases I have to have fork set to "yes" because I'm specifying an alternate jvm for the junit block.

Maybe the classpath length issue is worth exploring. I know that in my case the ant script that's failing the fork has a longer class path than the one that's working. I had another project with a longer classpath that was also failing to fork but I didn't really need to fork so I just set it to "no".